# How to override default behavior of the Zoom button in Qt?

Tags: macos, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have an application written using Qt5 in Python (PyQt5).

I want to override default behavior of the zoom (green "+" at top left) so it will set appropriate size of the window rather than maximize it to cover all available space.

I tried to override showMaximize, but that method was never called. My window is a subclass of QWidget without any additional window flags set (i.e. defaults are used).

How can I override the event or how can I tell the layout system size I want to be set once user clicks that button?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override `showMaximized` because it is not virtual. There is no way to override this action. But you can override `changeEvent`. It will be called when user maximizes the window. You can reset normal window's position and adjust its size.

```
void MyWidget::changeEvent(QEvent *e) {
  QWidget::changeEvent(e);
  if (e->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange) {
    if (isMaximized()) {
      showNormal();
      resize(200, 200);
      move(100, 100);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it lead to infinite loop (like when you use resize within resizeEvent)?

Comment: No because `resize` is executed only if `isMaximized`, and it becomes `false` immediately after `showNormal`, so it will be executed only once when user maximizes the window. I've tested this code.

Comment: Can I somehow handle this event *before* Qt process it and then cancel further processing? Qt5 resizes window using animation. It also has a bug(?) when Qt5 hangs up if you click the zoom button when part of the window is offscreen.

Comment: Try to install event filter for QApplication object and see which events are received when user maximizes a window. May be this event can be filtered out. Note however that it might be platform-dependent.

Comment: Unfortunately the solution in the answer didn't work. Looks like it ignores size set in this method due to some animation.